# Android webview display webpage in center-vertical (zoomed out)

Tags: android, webview, center, vertical-alignment

Is it possible to put the webpage on center-vertical while on max zoom out?
The webpage i put on webview only contains a area map and a image with 1500x750 pixel resolution. So the webpage exact width is around 1560px and height 760px

This is the map i created on full zoom out

https://i.stack.imgur.com/QUUkz.png

---

I want to make the webpage behave like this on full zoom out (note that this is not the actual output)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zkdu5.png